# FirebaseListObservable and flatMap

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, observable

I would like to have an observable that depend of the value of another observable. It's pretty simple, I just cannot find a way to do it

```js
user$: Observable<firebase.User>;
playlists$: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase,
          private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user$ = afAuth.authState;
    // error
    this.playlists$ = this.user$.flatMap(user => db.list(`/playlists/${user.uid}`));
}
```

The error I get is: 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable'.
  Property '$ref' is missing in type 'Observable'.

Comment: You typed `playlists$` as `FirebaseListObservable`, however `flatMap` returns an `Observable`..

Comment: Yeah because `db.list` return a `FirebaseListObservable` and I need a this  object type. Do you think I need to subscribe to the observable of `user$` to then create the `playlists$` observable? (removing the flatMap)

Comment: Just declare `playlists$` as `Observable`. That is what comes back from `flatMap`.

Comment: ... Or, what happens if you do the following: `this.user$.subscribe(user => this.playlists$ = db.list(`/playlists/${user.uid}`));`?

Comment: @developer033 that's the NOT-recommended way of doing this kind of chaining observables.

Comment: Yep @developer033  it will work, this is my actual workaround, but like Harry said, this is not the proper way to do it

Answer (score 0):

The annotation `playlists$: FirebaseListObservable<any>;` should be `playlists$: Observable<any>;`.

This is what `flatMap` returns. If you want to store the result of `flatMap` in a variable then that is the type annotation you *should* have.

Comment: The problem with that is, FirebaseListObservable contains other method like `push`, if I replace with Observable, Typescript will complain about the method `push` don't exists in Observable type